# debugging a php code

Tags: php, debugging

I have this problem, when I sometimes push my code from the developer server to the live server it's buggy, because it's not all time is the same version of all there are running on the live system and the developer system.

So now I search a method to find all bugs i think to developer one of myself or use a good one there all ready are developer out site on the internet.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Could you be more clear on the issue? Are you talking about version control?

Comment: Yes ofc, eg. when you get "on line 56 your $var not exists" i don't want to enable error handling on my live server but i think i want all the error logged so i can see what happen, :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable all error messages, you might use function [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and set it to 0, which means that all reporting should be turned off.

```
<?php
// You would place this where you initialize your application
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

There are also ways to specify different levels of reporting, but it is all explained in the documentation.

In order to log all errors which you encounter, you might use function [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). This function enables you to register your own way of handling specific errors. This also means that you can use logging inside of it or even some more advanced ways of error-handling.

```
<?php
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    // execute your logging procedure and some possible other
    // error-handling

    // This will disable PHP's internal error handler, even
    // if error_reporting is not set to 0
    return true;
}
?>
```

How you will log errors is another problem, but you might use your own way of dealing with this or some existing library. It might be too much for your purposes, but I really like Monolog, so you could check it out. There are also some other good libraries you could use, like log4php.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom error handler and have it e-mail issues to your mailaddress. This is how we use it in production.

Use `set_error_handler()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to set a custom handler.

See this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-email-error-logs-to-yourself-with-php/) how to set up a custom handler with mail functionality.